# Is it right to use link and controller together in directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

is it a good practice to use link and controller together in a directive? For the most examples I have seen, they either use link or controller alone.

To be more specific, if my directive's template, say it is a button element, has an 'ng-click' that invokes a function in the controller of my directive. At this time, if I add a link function to my directive and add another 'click' event to the same button element, would that cause some conflict or make either one click event ineffective?

This is the problem I am facing, not sure if it is right to use link and controller together.

Comment: Without seeing some code question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having two click events will always cause issues but that should be expected, don't do that. Use one or the other. Its not really necessary to use both at the same time so don't make things complicated. If you want to get nitpicky the controller function is initialized before the link function which sometimes matters.

Comment: And here's a plunkr with the scenario you described. Best way to learn is to just try it out, experiment. [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/RmdDfL?p=preview)

Comment: An element can have more than one click event listener. Clearly you can't duplicate attributes but that may not be how OP code is configured